# Create an inner shadow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In order to create an inner shadow, I always make a rectangle and add an inner shadow. The problem is then the rectangle still shows. I just want the pixels of the inner shadow and not the rectangle. I want to use it to overlay on another bitmap.

Thanks

Comment: Try setting the rectangle's fill to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change rectangle's (or any other shape's for that matter) fill to 0% in the Layers panel.